# PostgreSQL use function result in ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to use the results of a function call in the order by clause?

My current attempt (I've also tried some slight variations).

```
SELECT it.item_type_id, it.asset_tag, split_part(it.asset_tag, 'ASSET', 2)::INT as tag_num
FROM serials.item_types it
WHERE it.asset_tag LIKE 'ASSET%'
ORDER BY split_part(it.asset_tag, 'ASSET', 2)::INT;
```

While my general assumption is that this can't be done, I wanted to know if there was a way to accomplish this that I wasn't thinking of.

EDIT: The query above gives the following error `[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "******"`

Comment: What error do you get when you try `ORDER BY tag_num`?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I get the same error regardless of if I use the function call directly or if I use the column alias.

Comment: You can put it in a subquery, but that might impact performance, if there even is another way to do it. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT it.item_type_id, it.asset_tag, split_part(it.asset_tag, 'ASSET', 2)::INT as tag_num
FROM serials.item_types it
WHERE it.asset_tag LIKE 'ASSET%') as sq ORDER BY sq.tag_num` should work.

Comment: From the docs:  'ORDER BY can be applied to the result of a UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT combination, but in this case it is only permitted to sort by output column names or numbers, not by expressions.'

Comment: In particular, a function call is an expression.

Comment: @coladict If you'll add something to the extent of "...can't use expression....this will produce the desired" as an answer I'll accept it so that hopefully someone else can find this.

Comment: @BadZen: [The same doc page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-order.html) says, "The sort expression(s) can be any expression that would be valid in the query's select list." And OP isn't using "UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is generally OK, the problem is that for some row the result of `split_part(it.asset_tag, 'ASSET', 2)` is the string `******`. And that string cannot be cast to an integer.

You may want to remove the order by and the cast in the select list and add a `where split_part(it.asset_tag, 'ASSET', 2) = '******'`, for instance, to narrow down that data issue.

Once that is resolved, having such a function in the order by list is perfectly fine. The quoted section of the documentation in the comments on the question is referring to applying an order by clause to the results of `UNION`, `INTERSECTION`, etc. queries. In other words, the order by found in this query:

```
(select column1 as result_column1 from table1
 union
 select column2 from table 2)
order by result_column1
```

can only refer to the accumulated result columns, not to expressions on individual rows.